# ValueForKey: returns result in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nslog

I have an array that looks like this:

```
 {
    name = Size;
    "option_id" = 13;
    "product_option_id" = 380;
    required = 1;
    type = select;
}
```

and when i log an output like so:

```
NSLog(@"productOptions %@",[self.singleProductOptionsArray valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

it outputs the result inside an array so i cannout put it into a string:

```
 2013-08-01 11:10:33.116 vinylsdirect[210:907] productOptions (
 Size
)
```

i am using the same code in other arrays and everything is working fine so im not sure what is going on. i have also tried changing the NSLog like so:

```
NSLog(@"productOptions %@",[[self.singleProductOptionsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing my issues?

Thanks

Comment: is it an `nsarray` containing `nsdictionarys` ?

Comment: The data you show look like a dictionary, not an array. So as @SrikarAppal points out, your data are likely to be an array containing a single dictionary. That would also be consistent with your observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its an `nsarray` containing `nsdictionarys`. Iterate over it. See if this works ?

```
for (NSDictionary *prod in self.singleProductOptionsArray)
{
    NSLog(@"Prod: %@", [prod valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. i tried your code but i get the same message:     2013-08-01 11:30:51.824 vinylsdirect[256:907] Prod: (
    Size
)

Comment: i accepted your answer because its actually correct. it was myfault as i had this inside a for loop so i just had to change it a little fit my needs to: for (NSDictionary *prod in [self.singleProductOptionsArray objectAtIndex:i-1])

Answer (score 0):

When calling `valueForKey:` on an `NSArray` the defined return value is an array containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:` using `key` on each of the array's objects. So what you see is exactly what you are asking for.

Check exactly what types of objects you have and what the nesting is.

Comment: Nice anwser but sometimes i get NSArray as a result and sometimes only string?

Comment: well i called it twice for NSString and sometimes i have to add [0] at the end and sometimes i dont. Anyway it doesn't matter thanks!